# Monitoring Azure Data Factory access

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-security

Kind of a simple question, but puzzling...

Is there a stat in Azure services to monitor how many times data factory is / was accessed ?

So, as an example if an automated system is set up to make persistent API calls to ADF with the malicious intent exhaust it is there a way to monitor for that and gather some kind of stats?

Answer (score 1):

The monitoring built into the Azure Data Factory PaaS itself only monitors legitimate, authenticated usage. You can see this on the `https://adf.azure.com/en/monitoring/pipelineruns?factory=%2Fsubscriptions%...` dashboard.
[image: ADF Monitoring Dashboard]

Notice how the root domain is `adf.azure.com` - this is the same for all tenants using data factory around the world. Your specific subscription / instance are mere query parameters in the URL. Microsoft Azure is **fully managing** the actual hosting of this PaaS, which means they are entirely responsible for subverting any DDOS or similar bad-actor attempts on this service. It's not something you have to worry about, and therefore not something you have much visibility into.

If you ever needed or wanted to check in on how microsoft is doing with this, head on over to https://status.azure.com/status and search for the "Azure Data Factory" row:
[image: Azure Status Page]

This is really one of the biggest selling points of using a fully-hosted cloud PaaS such as Data Factory. You are no longer responsible for the hardware, or even range of ip addresses that back this service. No more than you have to worry about someone DDOS'ing `outlook.office.com` which probably services your entire organisation's email. I could happen, but if it did, it affects all of Microsoft's customers around the world, not just you personally, so there should be no expectation that you personally are doing anything special to mitigate against it.

---

Note that more generically if you want to monitor network traffic within your NSGs, iterfaces, VNETs etc in general on Azure, the thing to use is the Application Insights' Network Monitoring at [https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_Monitoring/AzureMonitoringBrowseBlade/~/networkInsights](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_Monitoring/AzureMonitoringBrowseBlade/%7E/networkInsights)
This is more generically applicable to all provisioned resources and services on Azure though, not something specific to Azure Data Factory.

Comment: Thank you.  This was my 'intellectual' understanding as well.  
It was interesting to know if there are / can be any visibility if someone purposefully attempts to DDOS the particular pipeline .. kind of to use it to overflow the database that a pipeline writes to (as an example)

Comment: @DmitriyRyabin Yes, in that specific case the Data Factory monitoring tab I mentioned (updated with screenshot) should tell you everything you need to know. If a bad-actor has successfully authenticated to your azure data factory instance and is triggering pipelines, those pipeline runs will appear here (as well as high-level metrics about runs and resource consumption), with details that can tell you how they are triggering it (e.g if it was via a public webhook, which conceivably could be leaked or abused internally).